# How to stack 3 smaller Divs next to one larger Div and rearrange as necessary for responsive layouts?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to learn how to stack 3 smaller divs next to a single larger div. I can achieve what I want if I put the three smaller divs in a wrapper, but then I am unable to rearrange as necessary for tablet and mobile layouts.

Please see attached file for layout desired.

[image: Layout desired]

Thanks,

DB

Comment: Do small research on `flexbox` and `@media` queries. It's lots of fun :)

Answer (score 2):

just check the bootstrap grid: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid